# C++ << no operator found

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, operator-keyword, stringstream

```
string toString() {

    std::stringstream punkte;
    std::stringstream name;
    std::cout << name << "hat" << punkte << "Punkte" << '\n'
    return 0;

  }
```

At this line of code. I'm receiving the error C++ << no operator found 
I can't figure out what my mistake is. I have read and tried different solutions. But nothing works. Can somebody please help?

```
 std::cout << name << "hat" << punkte << "Punkte" << '\n';
```

I also included this in my code:

```
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream, std::stringbuf
#include <fstream>
```

Comment: I think you mean: `std::cout << name.str() << "hat" << punkte.str() << "Punkte" << '\n';`

Comment: Can you add your error message?

Comment: Also `return 0;` - zero is not a string. You are attempting to create a string from a null pointer.

Comment: @DimChtz No, name and punkte are attributes. That I have already initialized.

Comment: They are not attributes, they are local variables. This code makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @JVApen binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ofstream'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call operator "<<" with a stringstream parameter. In other words:

```
std::cout << name;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
std::cout.operator<<(name);
```

And that operator<<(const std::stringstream&) function doesn't exists.

I think that what you want to do is assign each stringstream their values and then print both, isn't?

```
string toString() 
{
    std::stringstream punkte;
    std::stringstream name;
    name << "hat";
    punkte << "Punkte";
    std::cout << name.str() << punkte.str() << std::endl;
    return name.str();
}
```

Be careful with your return value, and remember that a std::stringstream is not a std::string. If you want to retrieve the std:string in the stream, you must call the `str()` method.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I'm trying to do. name and punkte .. that's name and points in english and they are already initialized. I'm trying to become this Output "Gamer <name> hat <points> Points".

Comment: The don't declare them again inside the function body, they will hide your attributes.
To print out that string try:
`std::cout << "Gamer " << name.str() << " hat " << punkte.str() << " Points." << std::endl;`

Comment: Hi @emaem116 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no overload of operator<<() that will format a std::stringstream to a std::ostream.  There error does not lie.